# Flatten image objects/layers in PDF, but leave text alone

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm trying to simplify PDF files to improve readability on my e-Reader.
For now, I'm using this ghostscript command to lose the color channels and downscale images:

```
gs                  \
  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER     \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite         \
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4      \
      -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray \
      -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen         \
  -sOutputFile="$2"         \
  "$1"
```

But PDFs with lots of text and images intermingling are still very slow to render. Is it possible to additionally merge every object on a page but text to a single image layer and remove every alpha channel?

EDIT: What seems to be really slow is the rendering of custom fonts. Would it be possible to render the text using unusual fonts, but keep the majority of the text, using a standard font, as is?

Comment: In essence, no. Of course with software pretty much anything is 'possible'. I can conceive of ways to achieve this, but it would require a great deal of coding. Your problem is probably that your source PDF files contain transparency, which always makes rendering slow. PDF doesn't have an alpha channel (exactly) it does have transparency which is **much** more complicated. If you set the CompatibilityLevel to 1.3 that will be removed and the whole file rendered to an image. There's no other way to deal with flattening transparency.

Comment: Problem is that I completely lose every text information. Plus how do you set the resolution at which this will be rendered (like 200dpi). Also is that possible to render everything as an image but keep text inside so researching words in the document may still work?

Comment: Yes, if there's any transparency, and you run to 1.3, then the whole page will be rendered. In Ghostscript you control the resolution with the -r switch. No you cannot render render everything and keep the text. Well, again, you could extend the existing software to do so, it cannot do so right now.

Comment: OK, that was because I remember having encountered PDFs generated with (I believe) Adobe Pro, which were scanned text documents where the OCR integrated the text without altering the images.

Comment: OCR software can do this. The text is drawn in rendering mode 3 (neither fill nor stroke). As I said, there is currently no facility to do this with the pdfwrite device (and no plans to add such a feature either)